# passport-google-oauth : GooglePlusAPIError: Legacy People API has not been used in project

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-api, passport.js

**Note** : It could be duplicate of some SO questions, but going through those answers didn't resolve this issue.

Am trying to integrate google-oauth using passport-google-oauth as per [passport js doc](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/)  and [github example](https://github.com/bognix/express-passport-google-oauth-exmple.git).

**Facing this error**     ( It refer to some link, but link doesn't work )

```
GooglePlusAPIError: Legacy People API has not been used in project xxxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/legacypeople.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
    at D:\openSource\passport\express-passport-google-oauth-exmple\node_modules\passport-google-oauth20\lib\strategy.js:95:21
    at passBackControl (D:\openSource\passport\express-passport-google-oauth-exmple\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\openSource\passport\express-passport-google-oauth-exmple\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

As per some other answers on SO,  enabled Google+ API, Google People API and Contact API, but error remain same. I know Google+ and Google People API has been decommissioned as of now.

Let me know what Google API exactly need to be enabled to function Google Auth.  I need only to validate user and get basic profile during authentication.

In case it is not related with API enable, help me to find the error.

Code is posted below, and same is available at   [github example](https://github.com/bognix/express-passport-google-oauth-exmple.git)

**auth.js**

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth')
    .OAuth2Strategy;

module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        clientSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
    }, (token, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        return done(null, {
            profile: profile,
            token: token
        });
    }));
};
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    passport = require('passport'),
    auth = require('./auth'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

auth(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(cookieSession({
    name: 'session',
    keys: ['SECRECT KEY'],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.token) {
        res.cookie('token', req.session.token);
        res.json({
            status: 'session cookie set'
        });
    } else {
        res.cookie('token', '')
        res.json({
            status: 'session cookie not set'
        });
    }
});

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    req.session = null;
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']
}));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        failureRedirect: '/'
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.user.token);
        req.session.token = req.user.token;
        res.redirect('/');
    }
);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. How did you '..enabled Google+ API, Google People API and Contact API' because from what I can tell it can no longer be enable?

Comment: @Bryan - sorry, just saw your message, because there was no notification.. You don't need to enable any API but use only correct library.. as mentioned in accepted answer.

Comment: No problem, I managed to get it to work in the end using the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally issue resolved, there are multiple libraries with similar name.. i.e. passport-google-oauth , passport-google-oauth2 and passport-google-oauth20. After trying all 3,  [passport-google-oauth20](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth20) did work for me.

[passport-google-oauth2](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2) is github url but its about passport-google-oauth20.

Comment: Hello, I've been frustrated because of this same issue. may i know what's the exact error or need to enable any API?. I'm using the sample passport-google-oauth20 module for google login. please let me know 

Comment: @Shivasurya - sorry, just saw your message, because there was no notification. You don't need to enable any API, just use correct lib as mentioned in accepted. In my answer there is link for correct link and example I followed .. that was sufficient.. yes indeed its very frustrating error because of misleading multiple libraries and in correct messages.

Comment: This answer worked for me, thanks, but I should also mention that I could use passport-google-oauth if I enabled Google+ API, Google Drive API and Google Sheets API. I don't remember how I got to that point now though. Anyway, just use passport-google-oauth20! :)